# When is a topological fiber bundle Zariski locally trivial?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be algebraic varieties defined over the complex numbers. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of algebraic varieties such that $f$ is a locally trivial fibre bundle in usual complex topology. When is $f$ Zariski locally trivial?

Any comments, suggestions on how to think about the question will be extremely helpful.

Comment: You might have a look at [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158424/fibrations-with-isomorphic-fibers-but-not-zariski-locally-trivial?rq=1) and the answers there.

Comment: @tota: The function field of $Y$ is not algebraically closed. This is the relevant field, not $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: For principal G-bundles, this is related to G being a "special group" in the sense of Serre; the original reference is here: http://www.numdam.org/item/SB_1951-1954__2__305_0/

Comment: Name of @DanielLitt's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422902/when-is-a-topological-fiber-bundle-is-zariski-locally-trivial#comment1086846_422902):  [Serre - Éspaces fibrés algébriques](http://www.numdam.org/item/SB_1951-1954__2__305_0).

Comment: What do you mean by "fibre bundle in usual complex topology": a topologically locally trivial fibre bundle, or a holomorphically locally trivial fibre bundle? In the former case, the fibres need not even be isomorphic as complex manifolds (see e.g. Ehresmann's theorem, which implies that any smooth projective morphism of (smooth) varieties is a $C^\infty$ fibre bundle, but of course the holomorphic/algebraic structure can vary).

Comment: You'll want the map from the base to the moduli space of the fiber to be constant, for example if the fiber has no deformations, or if the moduli space and base have contrasting geometric properties (frequently if the base is a rational curve). After that, it becomes a question about the automorphism group of the fiber.

Answer (score 4):

Since you asked for "comments, suggestions" here are two thoughts off the top of my head:

1. In [*Torsion Homologique et Sections Rationnelles*](http://www.numdam.org/item/SCC_1958__3__A5_0/) by Grothendieck (Séminaire Chevalley, 1958), the case for principal bundles is worked out.  In particular, for $G$-principal bundles over $\mathbb{C}$ where $G$ is isomorphic to a product of groups of type $\operatorname{SL}_n$ or $\operatorname{Sp}_n$, if the (algebraic) bundle is locally trivial in the analytic topology then it will be locally trivial in the Zariski topology.
2. To learn how to "work around" the difference for cohomological computations, see the propositions in Section 2 in [*Hodge polynomials of $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$-character varieties for curves of small genus*](https://doi.org/10.1007/s13163-013-0115-5) by
   Logares, Muñoz, and Newstead.

Comment: Thanks @Sean Lawton for your answer.