# $P^1$ bundle over complex tori

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, fibre-bundles

Let $M$ be a fiber bundle over $\mathbb C^2/ \Lambda$ whose fibers are $P^1$. $M$ is a complex manifold of dimensional 3. Is there a classfication about such $M$. And can we deduce that $M$ is a trivial bundle up to a finite cover ?

Comment: Have a look at [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95009/severi-brauer-variety-and-finite-covering) and Sasha's answer. Complex tori have nothing special in this regard.

Comment: Thanks. A complex tori may not be an variety. Does the ramified covering mentioned in Sasha's answer exsit in this case ?

Comment: And the what does trivial means in [question 2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95009/severi-brauer-variety-and-finite-covering)? It means the bundle is trivial or the bundle is the projectivization of a vector bundle

Comment: It means the projectivization of a vector bundle — you cannot hope for more. And you are right, the existence is not guaranteed in the non-algebraic case.